# Solving differential eqn with no first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the solution of "$v$" from the following differential equation:

$$\frac{dv_x}{dt}= \alpha v$$
Where,
$v_x$=velocity in x direction.

$v$=resultant velocity of the body .

$\alpha=constant$.

Comment: Are you sure you know nothing about the relation of $v_1, v_2$? Do you know something about the position $s$ (where $v=\dot s$)? Perhaps you know acceleration is only horizontal for some reason? Or $v_2$ is changed by gravity? Otherwise one would have to assume that $v_2$ is a constant, or that $v_1(t)=v_1(0)-\alpha \int_0^t v_2(\tau)\mathrm d \tau$.

Comment: I doubt that you can say more than $v_2=-(1/\alpha)({\rm d}v_1/{\rm d}t)$ because the acceleration in the $x$-direction is independent from $v_2$.

Comment: Unless you have more relation between them... We have acceleration in the $x$ direction depends on $y$ which implies that the place in the $y$ direction depends on $x$ so I guess that this question supposed to be answered using energy and not force

Comment: Silently changing the statement is a bad idea. It makes previous comments and answers nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

Trivially,

$$v=\frac1\alpha\frac{dv_0}{dt}.$$

Comment: I suppose we need to find $v_2(t)$..!

Comment: @samjoe: oooops, right. This is trivial then !

Comment: Yes haha, I don't know what Op is upto. cheers :)

Comment: @samjoe I'm guessing he is trying to find relation between energy and force... Or OP just forgot some information

Comment: @Holo: let me doubt that. I see no kinetic nor potential energy terms, and a force proportional to a speed evokes viscous friction.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree, but if you get to this kind of equation without any more information it is probably a question that supposed to be solved with energy, and the OP try solving it with force, so I thought he may try to compare the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you are solving for $v$ then you need not integrate because it is isolated and is not being differentiated. Dividing by $\alpha$ will yield the solution

$$v = \frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{dv_0}{dt},$$

Did you mean you wanted to solve for $v_0$?

Comment: α is a constant here,not acceleration... and the body moves in my plane only while force acts along z direction...